# Google maps marker and Sencha touch 2

Tags: google-maps, sencha-touch-2

I have an application made in Sencha Touch 2 that uses a Google Map. The map is going to display the position of several markers loaded from a JSON file with an Store. My question is, how can I read the markers from my Store? how can I use the data from the store to generate the markers?

This is what I have and IT IS WORKING FIND because I have an inline array "neighborhoods":

The Map:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.detalleMapa', {
    extend: 'Ext.Map',
    alias: 'widget.detallemapa',

    config: {
        listeners: [
            {
                fn: 'onMapMaprender',
                event: 'maprender'
            }
        ]
    },

    onMapMaprender: function(map, gmap, options) {

        var neighborhoods = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(52.511467, 13.447179),
        new google.maps.LatLng(52.549061, 13.422975),
        new google.maps.LatLng(52.497622, 13.396110),
        new google.maps.LatLng(52.517683, 13.394393)
        ];


        for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
            var m = neighborhoods[i];

            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: m,
                map: gmap,
                draggable: false,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            });
        }
    }

});
```

The Store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.itemsStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.itemsstore',
    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.modelo'
    ],

    config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'MyApp.model.modelo',
        storeId: 'itemsStoreId',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/markersJsonFormat.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: ''
            }
        }
    }
});
```

So far everything works fine because I use the array-markers "neighborhoods" into the map-class, but how can I use the array that was loaded by the store from the file 'markersJsonFormat.json'?

any idea? 
Thanks! :)

PD: this is my app:

```
Ext.application({
    requires: [
        'MyApp.view.override.detalleMapa'
    ],

    models: [
        'modelo'
    ],
    stores: [
        'itemsStore'
    ],
    views: [
        'principalTabPanel',
        'navegacionView',
        'itemsLista',
        'detalleMapa'
    ],
    name: 'MyApp',

    launch: function() {

        Ext.create('MyApp.view.detalleMapa', {fullscreen: true});
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer in case someone is looking:

```
onMapMaprender: function(map, gmap, options) {

    var store = Ext.getStore('itemsstore'); // Ext.getStore('StoreId')
    var count = store.getCount();
    //debugger;

    store.load({
        scope: this,
        callback: function(records) {
            //debugger;
            this.processTweets(records);
        }
    });
},
```

Be careful because this will load the URL source again and will refresh the store content in case you already loaded.